# Django - Use postgres unaccent with django-filters library

Tags: django, django-filter

I have a Django app that uses postgres. I know that if i have the [unaccent extension from postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html) installed in the database, I can use like it's [described in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/lookups/#unaccent) to apply filters ignoring the accents in the words:

```
>>> City.objects.filter(name__unaccent="México")
['<City: Mexico>']

>>> User.objects.filter(first_name__unaccent__startswith="Jerem")
['<User: Jeremy>', '<User: Jérémy>', '<User: Jérémie>', '<User: Jeremie>']
```

In this app I'm also using the [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library. I was wondering if there is a way to use the unaccent extension in conjunction with django-filter to avoid rewriting all my search functions. Here is an example of the code used to filter:

```
class BranchesFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = CharFilter(
        label='Filial',
        label_suffix='',
        field_name='name',
        lookup_expr='icontains',
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = Branches
        fields = '__all__'
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replying this just in case someone has the same question. Turns out this is way simpler than i thought. By adding *unaccent__* before the lookup expression (just like it's described in the docs), the extension can be used with django-filters. Here's the example provided in the question:

```
class BranchesFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = CharFilter(
        label='Filial',
        label_suffix='',
        field_name='name',
        lookup_expr='unaccent__icontains',
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = Branches
        fields = '__all__'
```